# Is there a visual 'debug' tool for jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue with jQuery not traversing to my elements in a specific section of my code where it works everywhere else flawlessly. I am wondering if there a visual tool of sorts (for any browser although I prefer Chrome), that will show me exactly what jQuery is doing as it hops through the elements?

**EDIT**
So, I should probably make this clearer.

I can use the built in debuggers just fine, however it just shows me the functions that jQuery is calling - not the actual elements that it is looking at. I would like to see what it is actually looking at in the DOM because this code works in 4 other places with exactly the same HTML structure but it keeps failing in the fifth place that it is used.

Hopefully that makes more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) for Firefox/Firebug could help identify which elements have jQuery events attached. If *only* it could resolve those to *actual* functions.

Comment: While not what I was looking for, this helped me very much! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to debug javascript is use the built in tools in IE, Chrome and Firefox. You can also use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com) which provides a lot more information. I use firebug almost daily to debug more than just Javascript

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the browser debuggers but they're not showing me where jQuery is going, just the functions it's calling. And I need to figure out why it's not working in this particular case. Which is why I was looking for something visual. :)

Answer (score 1):

try [Blackbird](http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/). It's great for JS/jquery debugging. It can be hidden and left in production and shown with a hot key [F2]

Comment: A little more code intensive now that we're almost done with the project, but a very good tool to have in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Firebug :) You can use `console.log("Put text here / or variables")` 
It then shows up in the firebug "console" screen: http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but thank you :) I'm going to update my question to make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a tool that does what you want, although it would be very good.

#### Other solutions:

Some people don't like this way of debugging, but put `alert()`s in strategic places in your code to output values from certain variables.

**Update** As James Gregory says in the comments, `console.log()` would be much better than `alert()`s all over the place.

Another method is what I do, which is to add a `<div id="debug">` in a nicely visible place on the page, then `.append()` values and other stuff to it to see what's going on.

Comment: `console.log` would be a less intrusive way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I would check out QUnit.  You have to write your own unit tests but it should allow you to examine and traverse the DOM however you want.